# OpenID Connect session state integration

Tags: http, authentication, authorization, keycloak, openid-connect

My web application using OpenID Connect provider (Keycloak) to authenticate my users. Application is built as Angular application using express.js server.

I'm trying to implement functionality to enable logout users when session on Keycloak ends. To provide session checking i'm using **check_session_iframe** (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html).

My application successfully embedd iframe and communicate using messages, but always return **"changed"** message. Reason is that iframe cookies from Keycloak are filtered and browser has not information about Keycloak session.

[image]
[image]

Why cookies for iframe are filtered?